# Shift Operator: Number of low-order bits being used for char, byte, short and long.

Tags: bitwise-operators

In Thinking of Java, there's a session introduced **Shift Operators** saying the following:

"If you shift a char, byte, or short, it will be promoted to int before the shift takes place, and the result will be an int. Only the **five** low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used. This prevents you from shifting more than the number of bits in an int. If you're operating on a long, you'll get a long result. Only the **six** low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used, so you can't shift more than the number of bits in a long."

My question is, char is 16 bits, byte is 8 bits, short is 16 bits, long is 64 bits, but

1) why **five** low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used for char, byte or short and,

2) **six** low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used for long?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that when an expression like `1 << x` is evaluated only the low bits of `x` are used. `1 << x` is equivalent to `1 << (x & 0x1f)`, and `1L << x` is equivalent to `1L << (x & 0x3f)`.

> 1) why **five** low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used for char, byte or short and,

Five bits means you can shift any distance from 0 to `2^5 - 1` = 31. Shifting further than that would mean shifting past the end of an int anyway.

> 2) **six** low-order bits of the right-hand side will be used for long?

Six bits means you can shift any distance from 0 to `2^6 - 1` = 63. Shifting further than that would mean shifting past the end of a long anyway.

For example: `1 << 65 == 2`, because only the low five bits of 65 are used and 65 is `1000001` in binary, so the low five bits are just `00001 == 1` and `1 << 65 => 1 << 1 => 2`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your explanation Paulpro@.